# nested if vs one if in loop Python

Tags: python, sql, nested-if

I am trying to build on the fly valid SQL statement including boundary constrains. My question is is there any easy way to build valid SQL statement using for loop like below?

```
sql = 'SELECT * from table '
firststatment = True
r = dict(request.query)
for k,v in r.items():
    if firststatment:
        sql = sql + ' where {} = {}'.format(k,v)
        firststatment = False
    else:
        sql = sql + ' and {} = {}'.format(k,v)
```

or in such case is better to use a structure like

```
if bondarydate1 and bondarydate2:
    sql = sql + ' where year(date) between ({} and {})'.format(bondarydate1, bondarydate2)
    marker = True
elif bondarydate1:
    sql = sql + ' where year(date) = {}'.format(bondarydate1)
    marker = True
elif bondarydate2:
    sql = sql + ' where year(date) = {}'.format(bondarydate2)
    marker =True

if marker and boundaryparam2:
    sql = sql + ' and boundaryparam2 = {}'.format(boundaryparam2)
elif boundaryparam2:
    sql = sql + ' where boundaryparam2 = {}'.format(boundaryparam2)
    marker = True

if marker and boundaryparam3:
    sql = sql+' and boundaryparam3 = {}'.format(boundaryparam3)
elif boundaryparam3:
    sql = sql + ' where boundaryparam3 = {}'.format(boundaryparam3)
    marker = True

if marker and boundaryparam4:
    sql = sql + ' and boundaryparam4 = {}'.format(boundaryparam4)
elif boundaryparam4:
    sql = sql + ' where boundaryparam4 = {}'.format(boundaryparam4)
    marker = True

if marker and boundaryparam5:
    sql = sql + ' and boundaryparam5 = {}'.format(boundaryparam5)
elif boundaryparam5:
    sql = sql +' where boundaryparam5 = {}'.format(boundaryparam5)
```

basically I am trying somehow to rich valid SQL statement like below

```
SELECT * from x where date between bondarydate1 and boundarydate2  and column1 = dhkjf and column2 = 343
```

P.S:
Is there some short way to build SQL which will contain only boundary for hardcoded keys like `r['predefined']` and if `r = {'predefined':'someValue', 'sapmKey':'spamvalue'}` so that spam value won't be inserted in query?

Comment: Yes, but is not a good idea to build queries like that.

Comment: At a minimum, you need to use `?` for your second entry to the format block.  This way you don't run the risk of SQL injection.

Comment: You be might be reducing the amount of lines of code, but you are making it alot harder to read and understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, but it is not a good idea to build queries like that: it easily allows **SQL injection**.

You can do it with the following code:

```
constraints = ' AND '.join('{} = {}'.format(*t) for t in r.items())
sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE {}'.format(constraints)
```

But this is not safe: if the key or the value contains for instance backquotes, a hacker could aim to export your database.

I would advice to at least escape the values (usually - hopefully - a user has only control over the values), and then you can use placeholders like `%s`, and let a library like MySQLdb escape the values. For instance:

```
constraints = ' AND '.join('{} = %s'.format(k) for k in r.keys())
sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE {}'.format(constraints)
cursor.execute(sql, r.values())
```

Furthermore there exist a lot of Python libraries (like SQLAlchemy) where one can safely construct SQL queries (well of course given the libraries themselves are safe). Which will usually have a positive impact on the security of your application.

I thus strongly advice you to use some sort of library to talk to the database. Usually it will provide an additional level of abstraction which is nice, and furthermore it will usually protect you against most security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I am looking for